# Trying to install new graphics card and get beeping on start up

Tags: drivers, graphics

I am trying to install an EVGA GeForce GTX 750 Ti Super Clocked

The card does not require external PCIe power. It requires a 300 watt minimum power supply, which is what I have.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

I am pretty sure I installed it right. It was straight forward, I heard a nice click and the card fit snugly inside the slot.

When I try to boot, I get the blue HP welcome screen, followed by a series of intermittent beeps. There was a total of 3 beeps, but they were very spread out. Then, I just get a black screen with a cursor icon.

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

I used to own an ATI radeon card and I never uninstalled the drivers for that, because I didn't think it would be a problem.

note: although I am able to see the blue screen, hitting escape to bring up the start up menu does not work

**Edit in response to comments:**

I have an HP Pavillon HPE series, model number h8 1100z

I am not sure what kind of motherboard I have. I don't see any clear indications of a name or model number on it.

my power supply is a Bestec model number: ATX0300D5WC    it is 300 W

The only custom thing in the computer is this card, everything else is just what it shipped with.

My BIOS settings are default

**Update:**

I just put my old card back in and it booted right up.

I would like to uninstall my current drivers to see if that works, but I want to make sure I dont do something wrong.

System settings says: "Using X.org X Server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xorg-xserver-video-ati (open source, tested)"

I ran the following command: `sudo apt-get purge "xserver-xorg-video-radeon'`

ths removed the following packages:

```
xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg-video-ati
xserver-xorg-video-all
```

I was hoping this would uninstall my driver, but I rebooted and even though the packages are gone, I still have the same display driver

Comment: Sounds more like a general problem with your graphics card and mainboard or BIOS? I think the error occurs even before Ubuntu gets started, so I would guess this could be off-topic. You could better try to ask this on [SU] and google the meaning of the BIOS error beep code you received.

Comment: What exact model of computer do you have? If you assembled it, tell us exactly what power supply and motherboard you have, and what else is plugged into the motherboard. If you've made changes to your BIOS settings (e.g. overclocking), tell us exactly what you did.

Comment: @seth nothing happens

Comment: Could you try that off a livecd just to double/triple confirm its the OS?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't currently have a live CD with me, I can make one if I have to, but I can tell you I have swapped the card between this one and the old one twice now and all is well with the old card, it is only when I put the new one in that I get beeping.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to the original question:**

According to the [manual](http://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/EVGA_Graphics_Manual_English.pdf)...

> Problem: At boot-up, all you hear is a series of beeps from the
>   computer, but see no image on the screen.
>
> Cause: The beep sounds are a warning sound from the motherboard BIOS that says it cannot initialize the graphics card, this can mean one of four things:

1. The card is not seated properly.
2. There is a problem with the motherboard’s graphics card slot.
3. Supplemental PCI-E power is not connected to the graphics card.
4. There is a problem with the graphics card.

> Solution: Remove the card from the computer and reinsert it, making
>   sure that the card is seated properly in the slot, and then try to
>   boot the computer again. If this does not work then the problem is
>   either with the motherboard or the graphics card and you should
>   contact your hardware manufacturer for further assistance.

Also, ensure the previous card is removed or disabled AND the drivers/software for it are uninstalled.

Comment: Yes, I read that, except I DO see an image on the screen.

Comment: I have also re-installed the card a couple of times now

Comment: @LukeP Means its the 4th one then